# is there a problem when migrating from apache tomcat 7.x to weblogic 10.3.3 a project with primefaces 3.0M2 involved

Tags: weblogic, primefaces

For a particular reason i developed a web app in apache tomcat 7.x and now i have to deploy it in weblogic server 10.3.3, in my project i use JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.0M2 and every thing works fine under tomcat container, but in WLS i get and error on startup, a FileNotFoundException when loading ***primefaces-3.0M2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml***, but that's not all, some pages does not display and in the logs there's and entry saying: ***SEVERE: jsf.cannot_instantiate_behavior_error null***. I was thinking maybe WLS does not load the primefaces' behaviors and i put in my faces-config.xml the content of primefaces' faces-config.xml, but still nothing, any help would be accepted.

Comment: I don't know much about WebLogic but like other application servers it contains its own bundled JSF implementation where Tomcat does not.  If you have JSF implementation specific details in your `web.xml` file this may be the issue.  See about modifying your configuration to use the integrated WebLogic JSF implementation or see documentation for how to include `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` in your `WEB-INF\lib` directory to make sure the classloader uses these jars.

Comment: Hello, the problems with the JSF libraries included in weblogic 10.3.2 is the version (1.2), and i developed the application in the spec 2.0, so i put in the weblogic.xml file this:"<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>", for now i tries the myfaces release 2.1 and the problems disappear, but now my session beans behave weird, like they were request scope beans, each time i access some property it is created again, what may be happening???.